# How to make user placed element clickable?

Tags: java

I have a program where a person can place an element representing a warpgate on the screen. I'm wondering how you can find the position of the element afterwards so that clicks in that area can be captured by the program.

Heres what I have currently:

```
int xCoord22[];
int yCoord22[];
int numSquare22;

int warpGate = 0;

public void init()
{

    warpgate = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"image/warpgate.png");

    xCoord22 = new int[100];
    yCoord22 = new int[100];
    numSquare22 = 0;
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{

    warpGate(g);
}

public void warpGate(Graphics g)
{
    //Checks if warpgate == 1 then will make the warp gate where the user chooses
    if(warpGate == 1)
    {

        g.drawImage(warpgate,510,820,100,100,this);
        //Use the custom cursor  
        setCursor(cursor2);  

    }

    //Building the pylons
    if(Minerals >= 150)
    {

        for (int k = 0; k < numSquare22; k++)
        {

            g.drawImage(warpgate,xCoord22[k],yCoord22[k],120,120,this);
        //Makes cursor normal.
        setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        }
    }
}

public boolean mouseDown(Event e, int x, int y) 
{
    if(warpGate == 1)
    {
        if(Minerals >= 150)
        {
            xCoord22[numSquare22] = x;
            yCoord22[numSquare22] = y;
        numSquare22++;
        handleWarpGatePlacement();
        repaint();
        }
    }

    //Checks to see if the person clicks on the warpGate icon so you can build it
    if(x > 1123 && x < 1175 && y > 782 && y < 826 && onNexus == 1 && Minerals >= 250)
    {
        warpGate = 1;

    }
```

So, basically, when you click on `x > 1123 && x < 1175 && y > 782 && y < 826` you can place a warpgate. How can I make it so where ever you place it later on you can just click on it and it will Do like a `system.out.print("hey");` or something else?

Comment: What is a "warpgate"? First time I'm hearing this term.

Comment: Probably relates to a concept in a game.

Comment: If you are using a programming IDE (Eclipse, Netbeans, etc), you might consider autoformating (in Eclipse: ctrl+shift+f) your code before posting it here? Btw, @ArjunShankar: Warpgate and Pylons sounds extremly like Starcraft... ;)

Comment: @brimborium - Then I'd have to ask: What is "Starcraft"? :-P

Comment: @ArjunShankar: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StarCraft)

Comment: @brimborium -Thanks! :) My original question about "warpgate" was really about clarifying the question. The one about "Starcraft" was just rhetoric. Looks like there is a pending edit that fixes this, somewhat.

Comment: @ArjunShankar: Yes, I just wanted to clarify that the term warpgate in this case most probably does not refer to a programming concept.

Comment: @brimborium you sir are correct haha, I'm making starcraft for my finalProject in Comp Sci Ap (of course not the full game)

Answer (score 1):

You could put your warpgate image inside a JLabel and add a `MouseListener`:

```
label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
   System.out.print("hey");
 }
});
```

Comment: I guess (from his code sample) that he already did this. He has a mouseDown implementation in his class, so I guess the class is a Component implementing MouseListener.

Comment: @brimborium Yes, I agree that he could probably also do label.addMouseListener(this) but this is not my point. My suggestion is to exploit the JLabel component by putting the image inside one. Still, I have to admit that given this is supposed to be a game, your solution is the better one. +1

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your code is not really a SSCCE, but I guess this code is in some sort of Component (perhaps JLabel?). You already implemented a MouseListener in there. Now you just need to save the position of your placed warpgate and then check for that position instead of your constant values in the MouseListener:

```
int minerals = 300;
Vector<int[]> warpgatePosition = new Vector<int[]>();
private final int warpgateDimX = 52, warpgateDimY = 44;

public boolean mouseDown(Event e, int x, int y) {
  boolean clickedOnAWarpgate = false;
  for (int[] p : warpgatePosition) {
    if (x > p[0] && x < p[0] + warpgateDimX && y > p[1] && y < p[1] + warpgateDimY) {
      clickedOnAWarpgate = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (clickedOnAWarpgate) {
    // we can not build one as there is already one there
    System.out.print("hey");
  } else {
    if (minerals >= 150) {
      warpgatePosition.add(new int[] {x - warpgateDimX / 2, y - warpgateDimY / 2});
      repaint();
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

So I have just built a Vector with the Warpgate positions in it.

EDIT: Of course, the position of your warpgates (as well as mineral count, warpgate size, etc) should ideally not be saved in this class. I have just put them there to make it compact.

Comment: If they don't belong there, don't put them there.  Don't get in the habit earlier of saying "Oh, I'll just put them here for the time being."  because you'll discover there is never enough time to undo all the crap you shouldn't have done in the first place.

Like waste time playing WarCrack.

Comment: Well, It might be a little bit counterproductive to change his whole software design when he was just asking about one single thing. I think it is very important as well, that's why I added it in the edit. +1 to you ;)